# Java, deck of cards, card class, need to get it all working together

Tags: java, class, methods, call, shuffle

I have an assignment for my summer class.  FYI, I'm super new to programming in general and this is my first time with java and it's a summer class so it's going super fast (please be nice!) lol.

Basically I started writing my code in one class, then I split it up into a Card class and a DeckOfCards class and I now need to figure out how to get it all to work together.  I get a little confused with calling methods sometimes, especially when separate classes are in play.  I think I just need a method to deal out five cards that also tells how many cards are left in the deck.  Then get it all working together correctly.  Also, I need a toString method but I honestly do not know how to go about that.  Any help is greatly appreciated!  If you could help explain things too that would be awesome!  I think I have everything SO FAR correct but I could be wrong and I'm sure there are better ways to write the code, I'll take any suggestions for a cleaner look too.  FYI, I think the prof would rather arrays then enums since we're dealing with arrays right now.

Here are the directions...
Design and implement a class called Card that represents a standard playing card. Each card has a suit and a face value. Then create a class called DeckOfCards that stores 52 objects of the Card class. Include methods to shuffle the deck, deal a card and report the number of cards left in the deck. The shuffle methods should assume a full deck. Create a driver class (CardsGame) with a main method that deals five cards from the shuffled deck, printing each card as it is dealt. Make sure to write the appropriate constructors, getters, setters, toString and other methods as required for both classes.

The main class, CardsGame Class

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CardsGame {
    public static void main (String [] args) {  

   }
}
```

Card Class

```
class Card {
   public static final int SPADE   = 4;
   public static final int HEART   = 3;
   public static final int CLUB    = 2;
   public static final int DIAMOND = 1;

   private int rank;
   private int suit;
   private static final String[] Suit = {"Hearts", "Clubs", "Spades", "Diamonds"};
   private static final String[] Rank = {"Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};                     

   private int cardSuit;
   private int cardRank;

   public Card(int suit, int rank) {
      if (rank == 1)
         cardRank = 14;     // Give Ace the rank 14
      else
         cardRank = (int) rank;
         cardSuit = (int) suit;
   }

   public int suit() {
      return this.cardSuit;         
   }

   public String suitStr() {
      return(this.Suit[ this.cardSuit ]);                                
   }

   public int rank() {
      return this.cardRank;
   }

   public String rankStr() {
      return ( Rank[ cardRank ] );
   }


   public String toString() {
      return ( Rank[ cardRank ] + Suit[ cardSuit ] );
   }
}
```

DeckOfCards Class

```
class DeckOfCards {
   public static final int NEWCARDS = 52;
   private Card[] deckOfCards;         // Contains all 52 cards
   private int currentCard;            // deal THIS card in deck

public DeckOfCards( ) {
  deckOfCards = new Card[NEWCARDS];
  int i = 0;

  for ( int suit = Card.DIAMOND; suit <= Card.SPADE; suit++ )
     for ( int rank = 1; rank <= 13; rank++ )
         deckOfCards[i++] = new Card(suit, rank);
         currentCard = 0;
 }


   //shuffle(n): shuffle the deck
   public void shuffle(int n) {
      int i, j, k;
      for ( k = 0; k < n; k++ ) {
          i = (int) ( NEWCARDS * Math.random() );  // Pick 2 random cards
          j = (int) ( NEWCARDS * Math.random() );  // in the deck?

  //swap these randomly picked cards
      Card temp = deckOfCards[i];
      deckOfCards[i] = deckOfCards[j];
      deckOfCards[j] = temp;
   }
  currentCard = 0;   // Reset current card to deal
  }
}
```

Comment: Well you need code in main to figure out if it's truly correctly responding the way you want it too...

Comment: This code was written so many times that it must be all over the internet.  Though I suggest you go through a decent tutorial on Java classes and methods first.

Comment: Dude, if you don't ENJOY working this problem out on your own, then find something else that you like doing. Most of us love coding.  Just take a breather, take some time, and have fun.

Comment: It's not a matter of not enjoying it, I'm just having trouble figuring it out.  I've literally only had 5 classes and it's a summer class.  If I knew how to solve the problem I wouldn't be posting here.

Answer (score 1):

## How do I get it all to work together?

### How do I instantiate the deck of cards?

To instantiate the deck of cards, use the following code `DeckOfCards deck = new DeckOfCards();`

### How do I call the methods of this class?

To call a method in the class DeckOfCards, you first need to instantiate an object of type DeckOfCards (which we just did). Then, you simply refer to the instantiated variable name (deck), put a **.**, and call the name of the method.

```
public class CardsGame {
    public static void main (String [] args) {  
        DeckOfCards deck = new DeckOfCards();
        //call shuffle
        deck.shuffle();
   }
}
```

### DeckOfCards class structure

Currently, I don't believe the methods you wrote in DeckOfCards are accessible. function shuffle() should be placed **outside** of the constructor. If you wish to call it inside your constructor, simply call `shuffle();`

### toString

Here is an example toString method for DeckOfCards

(note this should be placed after the constructor)

```
@Override public String toString() {
  return "DeckOfCards";
}
```

Comment: Do I not need to create a deal method?  Should be placed in the constructor I know my questions probably seem stupid but, do I have to call every single method I've created? I see you instantiate the DeckOfCards but do I have to do the same to card class in the deckOfCards class?  I wasn't sure if the Cards class and DeckOfCards class were working together or not.  Also, does the toString method only need to return "DeckOfCards" ?

Comment: @user3862586 I'm not going to do your homework for you, and skipped over your homework instructions. I gave you a basic example on how to instantiate an object and call a function with it. If a deck should contain Card objects, then yes you should instantiate 52 objects of type Card and add them to an array. toString can return whatever you want it to return. edit: No, you don't have to call a function if you don't want to.

Comment: I'm by no means asking you to do my homework I've done a whole lot myself I'm just having trouble getting everything to work together.  I don't expect you to write the code I just was hoping for an explanation of how I can get it working.